# Android - how to exclude jar files of Library in our application?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I am using 2 libraries in my application,which are having some common jar files.
So when i am trying to compile my application i am getting duplicate entry exception.I tried to exclude those jars in build.gradle for that perticular library project .
The code i wrote is

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile(project(':JIRAConnect')) {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore'
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    exclude group: 'com.nostra13', module: 'universalimageloader'
}
compile (project(':..:GlobalLib:MyGlobalLib')){
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore'
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'}
```

Can anyone give me the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you wanna remove those jar files

Comment: Make sure that the duplication libs are the same version.

Comment: Just use the same version, or change the jar with a maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

In the 'open Module Settings' option and then click on the item MODULES, click the Dependencies tab.

Excluding the two jar files that you added.
(Not to be removed from the project. Merely to exclude. May include back at any time if necessary.)